# Will accidentally wetting a page of an English Tanakh rend it non kosher?

Tags: tanach, water

If someone accidentally dropped a drop of water on a page of Tanakh will reading it, and the Tanakh is in English and the drop of water didn't fall on any name of HaShem. Will that make it non kosher ?

Comment: a book is not kosher or not kosher. A handwritten torah scroll or something on that level can be considered "kosher" or not, that is, fit for use, but a book with water on it is just wet. Until it dries. Until it dries.

Comment: I sense some confusion regarding the rules of erasing G-d's name, and if these rules apply to erasing G-d's name when written in a language other than Hebrew. If that's the concern of your question, please edit. Otherwise, perhaps, @Danno's comment should become an answer to your question.

Comment: I think this question has already been asked before but I can't find it

Comment: @DanF no, my question was about a wet Tanakh book in general, but you just inspired me for another question ;)

Comment: @Daniel I think it has.

Comment: @DanF Perhaps http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/61286/759 ?

Comment: @DoubleAA the asker of this question was me :D it was my previous account

Comment: @mil Then why are you asking again?

Comment: @DoubleAA my previous question was about the cover, now it's about the page, a content of the book